# Is an object with an event attached and no references to it eligable for garbage collection?

Tags: c#-3.0, garbage-collection

Quote from C# language specification 3.9:

> '2. If the object, or any part of it, cannot be accessed by any possible
>   continuation of execution, other than
>   the running of destructors, the object
>   is considered no longer in use, and it
>   becomes eligible for destruction...

For instance would the DispatcherTimer be eligible for garbage collection before the Tick event fires?

```
    public void DispatchCallbackAfter(Action callback, TimeSpan period)
    {
        DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer(DispatcherPriority.Normal, AppSettings.MainWindow.Dispatcher);
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(DispatchCallback);
        timer.Interval = period;
        timer.Tag = new object[] {timer, callback};
        timer.Start();
    }

    private void DispatchCallback(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        DispatcherTimer t = (DispatcherTimer)sender;
        t.Stop();
        ((Action)((object[])t.Tag)[1])();
    }
```

NOTE: There is self reference to the timer in timer.Tag but I imagine that would not make any difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the `DispatcherTimer` is running, the `Dispatcher` has a reference to it, and it will not get GCed. Once the timer stops *and* there is no external reference to it, it can be collected. That is, if your only references to the timer and the callback are *within* the timer and the callback, and the timer is stopped, the timer can be collected.

You can tell that the dispatcher takes a reference to a running timer by looking in Reflector (or your favorite decompiler) and seeing that the timer calls `_dispatcher.AddTimer(this);` in its start function and `_dispatcher.RemoveTimer(this);` in its stop function.

Comment: Just for further clarification, an object that is not referenced, with or without event handlers, is eligible for garbage collection. However, as you point out, it's not going to be the case for `DispatchTimer` instances that are running. (+1)

Comment: OK, so in my example it is OK since the Dispatcher does maintain reference to the timer, however if it hadn't the fact there is an event attached would not keep it live?

Comment: @Feanor: You are correct. If you have `evt += obj`, then `evt` is keeping `obj` alive but there's nothing keeping `evt` alive.